# Mold spots on Porch ceiling

Tags: ceiling

I have what appears to be black mold growing on my porch ceiling. What is your recommended method for correcting that problem? The ceiling is white.

Comment: Is your porch enclosed or outside?  Adding a couple of pictures to your question would be a good idea please.

Answer (score 1):

I had black mold in my sunroom, and my solution was to hit it with bleach (mixed with water), then to scrap it off and remove it from the areas. I then hit the area with "Mold Control" from Home Depot (as it helps also prevent the spread of mold. I did this to the effected area plus 1m on either side. Then I painted over it with a mold-proof paint (talk to people in your area who can best advise stuff for your region and colour).

I hope this helps. But importantly, use proper PPE use a mask that blocks that stuff and googles! Be safe man!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming!

Answer (score 1):

If the mold is coming from humidity in the air, I would kill the mold with a 1:10 chlorine bleach solution and water, undiluted white vinegar, or use a commercial product made for killing black mold. Rinse, let it dry, and don't worry about stains. Use Kilz paint primer to paint over the stains. It is a pretty good product and covers over mold and other stains, including cigarette stink, cat/dog pee on floors, and numerous other sources of nastiness. Finish by painting with the appropriate paint of your choice.

If the mold is a result of a moisture leak from the roof above, you have a bigger problem. You will need to repair the roof first, then use the above method to get rid of and cover the mold.

Answer (score 0):

I'd nuke it with either the pressure washer or some bleach, depending on the surface.

If I thought the pressure washer would damage it, I'd use the bleach. Pump spray a bleach solution followed by a brush then rinse. If I think the bleach would ruin it, I'd start with soap and a brush.